# monitoring multicast stream bandwidth

Tags: bandwidth, streaming

I have my own  application(based on VLC Library). It's used to multicast a stream from server to client via the mmsh protocol. It streams 1 file from the server to 2 clients.

- How can I monitor the multicast stream's bandwidth to make sure that if there are 2 clients or more, I will only use the bandwidth equal to one stream
- Do I need a special router/configuration for this? If so. please tell me how I would be able to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of traffic monitoring tools that can do this. [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) and [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net) are two of the most commonly used ones.
There are also a number of commercial solutions available.

All of these rely on your system supporting SNMP or some other means of reporting the bandwidth being used...